# Maximum Principle for Positive Laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $D$ be an open, bounded, connected region in $\Bbb R^2$, and suppose $u$ is a continuous real-valued function on $\bar{D}$ that is $C^2$ in $D$. Also suppose that $\Delta u>0$ in $D$. I have heard that the maximum principle holds in this case, i.e., $u$ attains its maximum on the boundary of $D$, but how can I show this? For harmonic functions, we may use the mean value property, but I cannot apply the same thing in this case, so I got stuck.

P.S. I don't know so much about harmonic function theory(only a little bit), but I know quite of complex function theory, so it may be good to use complex function theory.

Comment: A $C^2$ function with $\Delta u > 0$ *is* harmonic.

Comment: @Martin R Isn't the definition of harmonic function $\Delta u=0$?

Comment: You are right. I meant subharmonic.

Comment: assume you have a local maximum inside, then it is a critical point (partial derivatives of order $1$ are zero), and then we can assume that the discriminant of the Hessian is nonzero (otherwise just take $f+\epsilon (x^2+y^2)$), hence by usual 2 variable calculus, it must be positive; but then $f_{xx}, f_{yy}$ must have same sign, hence by the Laplacian condition they must be positive and this implies we actually have a minimum there

Comment: Should have been $-\epsilon((x-a)^2+(y-b)^2)$, where the point on cause is $(a,b)$, as that preserves the local max property and the positive laplacian at $(a,b)$ for small enough $\epsilon$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subharmonic function satisfies an averaging *inequality*: If $x\in D$ and if $B\subset D$ is a ball centered at $x$, then $|B|^{-1}\int_B u\,dx \ge u(x)$. (Here $|B|$ denotes the area of $B$.) [Given your interest in complex function theory, Ransford's book *Potential Theory in the Complex Plane* will be of interest.)